# capybara current path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I'm trying to make a simple login example test in capybara where you use the user email and password to login, and it redirects to root_url with a notice "logged in"

For some reason capybara reports that I am at login_path "/login" after I use click_on log in, but when I run it rails s I am at root_path "/" with my notice.

What have I missed in either capybara or my test app?
All relevant code should be below.

controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "logged in"
    else
      redirect_to login_path, notice: "Email or password incorrect"
    end
  end
```

view/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sessions Log In</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= label_tag :password %><br />
   <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "log in" %> </div>
<% end %>
```

login_spec.rb

```
it "should let you login with correct password" do
  user = Factory.build(:user)
  visit login_path
  fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
  fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
  click_on "log in"
  current_path.should == root_path
  page.should have_content("logged in")
end
```

routes.rb

```
...
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
...
```

Factories.rb

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:email) {|n| "a#{}@a.a"}
  f.password "a"
end
```

Comment: Can you verify that you are actually logged in? Try placing `page.should have_content("logged in")` before asserting current path.

And why are you only building a user instead of creating/saving it. I hope you realise `Factory.build(:user)` functions different than `Factory(:user)` and it doesn't actually save the user.

Comment: That was exactly right. I was meant to create instead of build.
Put it as the answer so I can tick it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that you are actually logged in?

Try placing `page.should have_content("logged in")` before asserting `current_path`.

And why are you only building a user instead of creating/saving it. I hope you realise `Factory.build(:user)` functions different than `Factory(:user)` and it doesn't actually save the user.

Comment: The reason this answer works is that `have_content` waits for the content to appear on the page, whereas `current_path` seems to jump the gun.

Comment: Although this is an old thread, it ended up as the first Google hit. For future references, know that Capybara also has the have_current_path smart matcher. [capybara](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RSpecMatchers#have_current_path-instance_method)